# Java Class Derivatives

Tags: java, class

When you have a derived class from X called Y and you have A derived from Y does that mean A is derived from x?  To sum up A is a grandchild of X is it derived from x?

```
class X {}
class Y extends X {}
class A extends Y {}
```

It would help to understand how I would be able to apply a grandparent class and variables within a grandchild class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not if it is me or everybody, yet your question is extremely hard to understand

Comment: @KickButtowski I think it's you, He ask if heritage is transitive

Comment: @azro I saw the code and make more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is,

> **Yes**.

[image: inheritance]

---

If `class X` had any non `private` instance methods or variables, all of them are inherited to `class A` through `class Y`.

```
class X {

    int z = 2;

}

class Y extends X {
}

class A extends Y {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new A().z);
    }
}
```

The output is,

```
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course A is derivated by transitivity from X, so you can do :

```
public class X {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("X");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X foo = new A();
        foo.print();      // X
        Y bar = new A();
        bar.print();      // X
    }
}

class Y extends X {   
}

class A extends Y {  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An A's instance can be upcasted to X, yes, but anyway X can just encapsulate it's methods and variables that A will not be able to access them. So it is not only about inheritance – it is about encapsulation too, because it does a big impact on inheritance in java.